# How to validate that two fields have the same value in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I would like to verify that the email confirmation field has the same value as the email field on my form.  I want to show an error massage when it does not match. How can I do that on the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com), you can use the Show Custom Error option to show error messages for any reason.

In this case, you can show an error message when your two email address fields do not have the same value.  Here are the steps to do this:

1. Add an `Email` field called "Email"
2. Add a second `Email` field called "Confirmation Email"
3. For this confirmation field, select *Show Custom Error - When*
4. Switch to the *Advanced Editor* and enter this calculation: `=(ConfirmationEmail != Email)`
5. Click *Save* to close the conditional logic dialog
6. Enter the error message you wish to show when this error occurs

Here is what this will look like when you are entering the validation calculation:

[image]